# cocoa touch - problem updating subviews!

Tags: iphone, cocoa, touch

I have this UIViewController which contains an UIScrollView.
In the viewDidLoad method of the first controller, I create some UIViewControllers(defined through a NIB with an UILabel and an UIImageView inside,linking to IBOutlets done correctly), then I add them to the UIScrollView.

Problem is, I can see my views and scroll through them using the scroll view, but I seem to be unable to modify the text of the label and the content of the imageView using the methods [[UIViewController UILabel] setText] or [[UIViewController UIImageView] setImage]

I know it sound like a stupid question, but I can't get past it.
Any idea why?

Thank you guys.

Comment: `ViewDidLoad` or `viewDidLoad`? Note that Objective-C is case-sensitive and this might be the problem.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {}, also the rest of the method works fine..

Comment: Please correct your question (->viewDidLoad) to avoid other people picking up on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have resolved my problem. I was trying to modify the views before adding them to the UIScrollView.
If I call my methods after the [scrollview addSubView:myView], everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag the Label and ImageView.
tag means assign a integer value to label and ImageView and you can access using the tag.
You can assign tags in xib.
 Then you can access the view like this

```
[someController viewWithTag:(int)];
```

Comment: Hum, I am using the same control and XIB model for all the views contained in the UIScrollView(generating them with a cycle then adding via addSubView). That means they would all have the same tag right?Also I can't understand why my views aren't responding to direct commands without sending out any error.